# Getting images from media library and get_the_date() not working

Tags: functions, query-posts, date

I've got a function to display all images in the media library on a page. I would like to display the date of each image, but using get_the_date() only returns today's date.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function get_images_from_media_library() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' =>'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
        );
$query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
    $images[]= $image->guid;
}
return $images;
    }

function display_images_from_media_library() {

$imgs = get_images_from_media_library();
$html = '<div id="media-gallery">';

foreach($imgs as $img) {

    $html .= '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="" />';
    echo get_the_date('F j, Y');
}

$html .= '</div>';

return $html;

}
```

I could someone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: not necessarily related to the cause of your problem, but if you're using a function to run a `wp_query()` object, you might want it to also run `wp_reset_query()` at the end so it doesn't mess up other loops.

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_date` depends on the global `$post` variable. It is a bit hard to tell that that is the case but if you  look at the [source for `get_the_date`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1408) you'll see that it uses `get_post` and [it assumes `$post` if no other parameters are given.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/post.php#L386)

Your code never sets that `global $post` variable except for when your `WP_Query` initially runs. You need to refactor. I would return the post objects from `get_images_from_media_library` and construct a more standard Loop to process them.

I think this should be better.

```
function get_images_from_media_library() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' =>'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
  );
  $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
  return $query_images;
}

function display_images_from_media_library() {
  $imgs = get_images_from_media_library();
  $html = '<div id="media-gallery">';
  global $post;
  if ($imgs->have_posts()) {
    while($imgs->have_posts()) {
      $imgs->the_post();
      $html .= '<img src="' . $post->guid . '" alt="" />';
      $html .=  get_the_date('F j, Y');
    }
  }
  $html .= '</div>';
  return $html;
}
echo display_images_from_media_library();
```

Comment: That works perfectly, and with a clear and concise explanation. Very much appreciated.